# In HTML, how can I get an input box to stretch in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have uploaded the following simple HTML code to http://losthobbit.net/temp/anchor.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Anchor Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <input maxlength="250" type="text" name="Text2" id="Text2" style="position: absolute;
                top: 13px; left: 265px; right: 15px; height: 20px; text-align: Left">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I've specified the left and right, but not the width, in order to get it to stretch.

In Chrome it stretches as one resizes the browser, but this does not work in IE8 or FireFox.  Any ideas about how I can fix this?

Thank you

Please note that people are suggesting I use a width percentage... unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.  I want the exact same behaviour that I have in Chrome, which is that of a left and right anchor.  This means that the stretching is not a fixed percentage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the `<input>` a parent element, set your current styles on that and give the `<input>` element `width:100%`.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%">
  <span style="position: absolute; top: 13px; left: 265px; right: 15px; height: 20px; text-align: Left">
    <input maxlength="250" type="text" name="Text2" id="Text2" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
  </span>
</div>
```

> **Working demo: http://jsbin.com/ayiwa5**

Comment: Thank you. Alternatively, if I transfer the sizing to the div, then it also works.  If anyone has any other solutions, I'd still like to see them.

Comment: Yep, that would work too.  Since your `<div>` was full page width and the `<input>` wasn't, I assumed you would be having something else in the `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the percentage width explicitly on the `<input type="text" />` for IE and firefox.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKnJT/2/

It is quite quirky with the absolute positioning but it will make the textbox resize with the browser window.

Note: if you remove the `style="width:100%;height:100%"` from the div it will **still** resize in Chrome.

**[Update]**
Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/LKnJT/5/. Tested in chrome and IE. It keeps the textbox between the left and right specifications.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Anchor Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;left:150px;right:20px;">
            <input maxlength="250" type="text" name="Text2" id="Text2" style="text-align:left;width:100%">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it doesn't solve my problem.  I want the exact same behaviour that I have in Chrome, which is that of a left and right anchor.  This means that the stretching is not a fixed percentage.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a solution that makes the textbox stretch between the left and right anchor points.

Comment: Yip, that's what I meant by my comment on Andy's answer :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How much do you want it to stretch?  You can specify width but set its value in terms of percentage:

```
width: 40%;
```

**UPDATE:**

Apply this to the input:

```
float: right;
width: 80%;
```

Just make sure to [clear float](http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html) on the parent container.

Comment: I want it to stretch the same way it does in Chrome... according to how much you resize it.  The same behavior as anchoring to the left and right.

Comment: ... basically that means the width won't be a fixed percentage.